# Know what changes are made into a database table, using Entity Framework Core

Tags: sql-server, database, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework Core for my project, and most of the things are customizable in my project like the public portal UI, and widgets, and these customization changes are reflected back to my database.

Now I want to be notified when a user makes any change to any of the widgets or styling from admin panel and also what changes he made.

Does Entity Framework Core provide such a functionality to track change of data?

Comment: are you wants to show a simple message for changes or show all detail of changes? are you wants to keep all change history?

Comment: Which is it - Entity Framework 6 (the "classic" EF on the full .NET framework), or EF Core (on .NET Core) ?? Those are **NOT** the same and offer quite different capabilities in certain areas !

Comment: I wants all the detail of changes made into my database. @MahdiRahimi

Comment: I am working on EF Core (.Net Core) @marc_s

Comment: @MohsinAliKhan you can do this with sql server services automatically. this solution can help you???